# How to draw on Canvas widgets embedded inside a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

This is a really basic requirement, but I'm stuck!  For WPF/.Net - I just want to dynamically draw into a Canvas column in my ListView.  One failed attempt:

```
<ListView name="myGridView">
    <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnA" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ColumnA}" />
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ColumnB}">
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SUSPECT!
        <Canvas Name="canvasColumn" Width="100" Height="20" />
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

Inside my code, I have a class "MyData" with fields bound to the non-canvas ListView columns.  I loop through some "Whatever"s creating items in the ListView:

```
foreach (Whatever whatever in whatevers)
{
    MyData myData = new MyData();
    myData.ColumnA = whatever.A;

    myData.ColumnB = new Canvas();
    Line line = new Line();
    line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
    line.X1 = line.Y1 = 1;
    line.X2 = line.Y2 = 100;
    line.StrokeThickness = 1;
    myData.ColumnB.Children.Add(line);

    myListView.Items.Add(myData);
}
```

This DOES NOT work: every row in the on-screen canvas column displays the text "System.Windows.Controls.Canvas".  Not terribly surprising - I've bound the column in the same way as the text columns and some toString conversion of the typename seems to kick in.  But, I've tried a few other things and just can't get the Canvas displayed.

I have also tried removing the column binding marked "SUSPECT" above, and myData's ColumnB field, seeking a way to refer to the canvas widgets via the listview, i.e. something of the form:

```
myListView.reference-to-new-row-and-canvas-column = theNewCanvasIDrewOn;
```

Some of my searches have turned up ugly messes of Styles, ItemPanel configs etc.: please - if that's necessary, I at least hope it can be kept minimal....

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Tony

## UPDATE

For my purposes, the minimal solution appears to be adding a DataTemplate to App.xaml's Application.Resources tag:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    <Canvas Width="60" Height="20" Background="Red" ClipToBounds="True" >
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding myCanvasField}" />
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

and defining a GridViewColumn as:

```
<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" Header="title" />
```

Thanks to Dean for pointing me in the right direction, and to [Binding to Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135438/binding-to-canvas) for canvas-specific details.  I then "draw on" the Canvas property member of the object I add to the ListView.

Comment: What kind of drawings do you have?

Comment: @Dmitry: The listview will display "tasks", and the pictures will show bars for start dates, promised delivery date, expected delivery date etc. on a logarithmic scale - basically an at-a-glance check of how the task is progressing. Later I might get fancier and want to indicate holiday/leave periods or something....

Comment: As an aside: If you're talking about "drawing on" a Canvas, you don't really "get" WPF. WPF uses retained-mode graphics, which is very different from WinForms' paint events; and WPF's Canvas is a layout panel, not a drawing surface. You don't "draw on" a Canvas; you add controls/elements to it. If you want a surface to "draw on", look into DrawingGroup or WriteableBitmap.

Comment: @Joe: I understand the distinction, but in the end - same diff ;-).  A canvas is capable of displaying what I need....  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a CellTemplate rather than a Canvas directly

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx

Comment: I think a bigger question here is how to make your canvas talking to your Business Object.

Comment: @Dean: thanks for the tip. I changed to `<GridViewColumn Header="..." CellTemplate="{StaticResource ct}" />` and in App.xaml added `<DataTemplate x:Key="ct"> <Canvas ... > <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CanvasProperty}" /> </Canvas> </DataTemplate>`. Will append this to the question for easier reference. All good :-).

Answer (score 1):

You could impliment the TaskVisualizer as a custom control and then just host that in your list template.  This separates out your task visualization code from your global UI code.  This has the advantage that its easy to reuse the task visualation else where - eg you could easily show the same graphic in a tooltip when hovering over a task in some other view.

Comment: Hi Ricibob, thanks for the suggestion - it does sound clean conceptually - but as I don't currently have any insight into how to do that I pursued a more minimal albeit coupled approach.  I might try this one day as a learning exercise.  Thanks, Tony

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Yes, as with all things WPF there is some considerable uptime in sorting out custom controls - but its rewarding if you have the time to invest!  I found Sams - WPF Control Development Unleashed a good starting point in case your ever interested in this route.

Answer (score 0):

here's my take on it. The idea is to use a mini DSL to exchange the information between your canvas and your business objects.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DrawInCanvas.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DrawInCanvas"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="g">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Item1}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bar">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                    Height="20"
                                local:CanvasDrawing.Drawing="{Binding Item2}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DrawInCanvas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // just a sample
            Dictionary<int, string> barDefinitions = new Dictionary<int, string>(3)
            {
                { 1, "100$red" },
                { 2, "220$yellow" },
                { 3, "40$blue" }
            };

            this.g.ItemsSource =
                Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(t => 
                    new Tuple<int, string>(t, barDefinitions[t]));
        }
    }

    public class CanvasDrawing : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Drawing",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CanvasDrawing),
                new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback((o, e) => 
                {
                    CanvasDrawing.Draw((Canvas)o, (string)e.NewValue);
                })));

        public static void SetDrawing(Canvas canvas, string drawing)
        {
            canvas.SetValue(CanvasDrawing.DrawingProperty, drawing);
        }

        public static string GetDrawing(Canvas canvas)
        {
            return (string)canvas.GetValue(CanvasDrawing.DrawingProperty);
        }

        private static void Draw(Canvas canvas, string drawing)
        {
            string[] parts = drawing.Split("$".ToCharArray());

            canvas.Width = double.Parse(parts[0]);
            canvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(parts[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for the suggestion and code.  I wasn't too sure how to use this, as it seems to abandon the ListView and adopt a DataGrid?  Not even clear to me how to add say a Line to the canvas, or how a suitable "string drawing" value can be created.  Something for me to return to if/when I know more .NET.  Thanks, Tony

Comment: Hi Tony, the easiest wat to do what you're looking for is Dean's answer.